# Birthday of Friend's using facebook api 2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, android-simple-facebook

I am trying to get birthday of my friends, those who have installed my sample app. Below is my code.

```
 new Request(simpleFacebook.getSession(), "/" + id, null, HttpMethod.GET,
                                    new Request.Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                            String rawResponse = response.getRawResponse();
                                            AppLog.showLog(TAG, "Friend response is " + rawResponse);
                                        }
                                    }
                            ).executeAsync();
```

But in response there is no any "birthday" filed.

I also used simplefacebook library. Using below code

```
PictureAttributes pictureAttributes = Attributes.createPictureAttributes();
                            pictureAttributes.setType(PictureAttributes.PictureType.SQUARE);
                            pictureAttributes.setWidth(250);
                            pictureAttributes.setHeight(250);
                            Profile.Properties properties = new Profile.Properties.Builder()
                                    .add(Profile.Properties.NAME)
                                    .add(Profile.Properties.BIRTHDAY)
                                    .add(Profile.Properties.PICTURE)
                                    .add(Profile.Properties.ID)
                                    .build();
                            simpleFacebook.getProfile(id, properties, new OnProfileListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(Profile response) {
                                    String id = response.getId();
                                    String name = response.getName();
                                    String birthday = response.getBirthday();
                                    String pictureUrl = response.getPicture();
                                    AppLog.showLog(TAG, "Single friend Detail: " + id + "\t" +
                                            name + "\t" + birthday + "\t" + pictureUrl);
                                    FbFriendsDao fbFriendsDao = new FbFriendsDao(LoginActivity.this);
                                    fbFriendsDao.openForWrite();
                                    fbFriendsDao.insertFriends(new FbFriendDto(id, name, birthday, pictureUrl));
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
                                    super.onException(throwable);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFail(String reason) {
                                    super.onFail(reason);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onThinking() {
                                    super.onThinking();
                                }
                            });
```

But it gives null in birthday filed.
Please help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @luschn mentioned, all `friends_*` permissions have been removed, including `friends_birthday`.

**However** it is still possible to get some data if:

1. The friend you want the birthday for is also a user of your app
2. The friend has provided the `user_birthday` permission (note you'll need this approved by FB)

You can do this by adding "birthday" to the `fields` key in `me/friends`:

```
me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday
```

Alternatively, you could simply save the user data to your own database when the user signs up and then retrieve it later, which would give you exactly the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> All friends_* permissions have been removed

That includes `friends_birthday`, so it is not possible to get the birthday of a friend anymore.